# What is the appropriate form of address for a university professor to a student member of a royal family?

Tags: etiquette, job, professionalism

In the Netherlands, Crown Princess Amalia is attending the University of Amsterdam. I'm curious about the proper etiquette for social interactions between staff and her on and off campus. What is the appropriate form of address for a university professor to a student member of a royal family, in and outside of class? I imagine that the context is important, such as whether the interaction is inside of university functions or not (e.g., during class). What other factors are related to a correct answer, if there is one? Is the answer consistent with other countries such as the United Kingdom?

Comment: If you are not sure how to address someone, ask them.  Their royal status does not change that.

Comment: “Amalia”. If she doesn’t like it, she can complain.

Comment: The Dutch people seem pretty chill with respect to titles.

Comment: In practice, I agree that one could a) ask, b) default to the setting, and that c) Dutch people are not so intense about their monarchy as some other countries. But there still might be a formal answer to this question.

Comment: does she carry a sign telling who she is? If not, good luck being recognized in first place...

Comment: @Mark There are not so many crown princesses in the Netherlands (1) that they are difficult to recognize.

Comment: @CameronBrick but at the same time, many people don't care about the royals in the Netherlands, so they might not even have a clue how she looks like. This isn't UK..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal answer is given by the [website of the Dutch Royal House](https://www.koninklijkhuis.nl/onderwerpen/titels-aanspreektitels-en-beschermheerschappen/aanspreektitels):

> Prinses Catharina-Amalia wordt aangesproken als Koninklijke Hoogheid en aangeschreven als Hare Koninklijke Hoogheid de Prinses van Oranje. De aanhef van een brief luidt: Koninklijke Hoogheid.

So the correct way to address Princess Amalia is as "Koninklijke Hoogheid". This does not change in anyway if the person addressing the princess is a professor or not. Since she is following an English-taught degree (Politics, Psychology, Law and Economics), it is probably also acceptable to address her in English, so using "Royal Highness".

How this works in practice I do not know, but surely her professors will have been briefed on the proper etiquette. Given the Dutch tendency towards egalitarianism in social interactions I suspect just "Amalia" might be fine.

Comment: That is a good resource. I was thinking earlier about context, not about the power or role of the professor; in class, I'm imagining other students wouldn't use the formal title. I can speak to the 'surely' comment, as I am such a professor, and I have not been briefed.